# Error when using cellfun to do regression on a cluster

Tags: matlab, regression, cluster-computing, linear-regression

I'm using Matlab 2016a on my university's cluster. My local PC has Matlab 2016b installed.

I'm attempting to do a very large regression using cellfun. The drought resistance and predictor layers are 2044x1572. The internal dimensions of "drought resistance" is 100x1 while the internal dimensions of "predictors" is 100x6, representing the different predictors for each cell.

```
d_regress=cellfun(@(x,y)regress(x,y),Drought_resistance,predictors,'UniformOutput',false);
```

When I run this code with sample data on my local PC I get no errors.

However, when I run this code on the cluster I get the error:

```
    Error using  *    
    Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
    Error in regress (line 93)
    b(perm) = R \ (Q'*y);
    Error in @(x,y)regress(x,y)
```

So then I fix the inner matrix dimensions so that they are 1x100 and 100x6.

Then I get the following error, which makes sense because of how regress works.

```
Error using  | 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in regress (line 66)
wasnan = (isnan(y) | any(isnan(X),2));
Error in @(x,y)regress(x,y)
```

I've been having to use `mldivide` on the cluster in order to do my regressions (`mldivide` gives me no errors), but I would prefer to use `regress` due to its additional functionality. Is there any way I can modify my code in order to use `regress`?

Comment: I have 2 advise:

1. try to take few cases and run a regress (without cellfun, just regress(Drought_resistance{i,j}, predictors{i,j})) to be sure it work on the data you have.

2. try to check again that the dimension of Drought_resistance and predictors is correct. maybe you have a problem of a dimension of one of the cell and not all of them. or better do it in 2 loops to see which value of i and j it have an error.

Comment: To help with debugging, write the code in a loop rather than `cellfun`, then you can output which loop iteration it's failing on and the current variables being used. `cellfun` is basically a loop in disguise anyway so you'll likely see very little performance difference.